# nginx error "ERROR: cannot launch /usr/local/bin/uwsgi - run is locked"

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have configured the `django_uwsgi` with `nginx`, in the log I'm getting this:

```
ERROR: cannot launch /usr/local/bin/uwsgi - run is locked
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try deleting the nginx pid file. 
Usually found at /var/run/nginx.pid